# Best way to reinitialize javascript modules after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a bunch of JS functions/modules defined as such:

```
m.revealer = function(){
    var els = doc.getElementsByClassName('js-reveal');

    if (els.length < 1) return false;

    var wh = win.innerHeight;

    function checkEls(){
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            var el = els[i],
                top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
                offset = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-offset')),
                target;

            offset = offset ? offset : 1;
            target = (wh * offset);

            if (top <= target && !u.hasClass(el, 'revealed')) {
                u.addClass(el, 'revealed');
            }

            if (top > target && u.hasClass(el, 'revealed')) {
                u.removeClass(el, 'revealed');
            }
        };

        requestAnimationFrame(checkEls);
    }

    checkEls();
};
```

And they are called via:

```
m.installSetUp();
m.pinner();
m.installMonitor();
m.revealer();
```

And within those, are various things, such as event listeners, etc. Some of which are bound to window or document. They keep their variables in their own scope except for things like window, or document event listeners.

When I'm using ajax to load pages, after the page has loaded and has it's new dom I recall those functions to get them to work:

```
function reinit() {
            doc = document;
            body = doc.body;
            m.navControls();
            m.introVideo();
            m.homeSnaps();
            m.techSwitch();
            m.minicartToggle();
            m.installationAnims();
}
```

However I seem to be running in to lots of bugs where things just aren't working correctly. Things that depend on scroll are off, listeners are assigned twice, etc.

How would I best go about fixing/making sure this doesn't happen in future?

**Please note: NOT using jQuery.**

If more code is required, I will provide where needed.

Thanks.